# Hibernate custom property accessor and dirty checking

Tags: hibernate, properties

I have a custom property accessor which modifies a value before setting it up on my object. The problem is that the object gets detected as dirty. Is there a way to reset the dirtyness of an object?

Comment: Would it be possible to tell hibernate to take the snapshot after an object is fully loaded?

Answer (score 1):

```
    @PostConstruct
protected void init() {
    SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
    EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
    registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.FLUSH_ENTITY).appendListener(customDefaultFlushEntityEventListener);
}
```

public class CustomDefaultFlushEntityEventListener extends DefaultFlushEntityEventListener{

```
@Override
protected void dirtyCheck(final FlushEntityEvent event) throws HibernateException {
    super.dirtyCheck(event);
    excludeIgnoreDirtyPropertiesFromDirtyCheck(event);
}

private void excludeIgnoreDirtyPropertiesFromDirtyCheck(FlushEntityEvent event) {
    String[] propertyNames = event.getEntityEntry().getPersister().getPropertyNames();
    int[] dirtyProperties = event.getDirtyProperties();
    Object[] propertyValues = event.getPropertyValues();
    
    if(dirtyProperties == null) {
        return;
    }
    
    List<String> ignoreDirtyPropertiesList = FieldUtils.getFieldsListWithAnnotation(event.getEntity().getClass(), IgnoreDirtyProperty.class)
    .stream().map(Field::getName)
    .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    List<Integer> newDirtyPropertiesList = new ArrayList<>();       
    
    for(int dirtPropertyIdex :  dirtyProperties) {
        
        if(!ignoreDirtyPropertiesList.contains(propertyNames[dirtPropertyIdex])  && !(propertyValues[dirtPropertyIdex] instanceof List)) {
            newDirtyPropertiesList.add(dirtPropertyIdex);
        }
        
    }
    
    int[] newDirtyPropertyArray = newDirtyPropertiesList.stream().mapToInt( index -> index).toArray();
    event.setDirtyProperties(newDirtyPropertyArray);
    
}
```

}

Ignore field from Dirty : `@IgnoreDirtyProperty @Column(name = "published") Boolean published;`

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need is use `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)`

For example

```
 @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
 public String getStringValue()
 {
   return this.stringValue != null ? stringValue : "";
 }
```

In this case Hibernate will use for dirty check the field value and not the getter.